# Why type casting not required?

Tags: c

Below are following code written in c using CodeBlocks:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    char c;
    int i = 65;
    c = i;
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(c));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(i));
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

Why when printing variable `c` after it was assigned with int value (`c = i`), there no need for casting to be made?

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: C is not strongly typed.

Comment: Your `printf` is using the wrong format specifiers for `sizeof` values.  You need to either cast the values to `int` or else change the formats to `%zu`.  Otherwise the code will not be portable.

Comment: @AbirBhattacharya: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

A cast is a way to explicitly force a conversion. You only need casts when no implicit conversions take place, or when you wish the result to have another type than what implicit conversion would yield.

In this case, the C standard requires an implicit conversion through the rule for the assignment operator (C11 6.5.16.1/2):

> In *simple assignment* (=), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the
>   assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left
>   operand.

`char` and `int` are both integer types. Which in turn means that in this case, the rules for converting integers are implicitly invoked:

> 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if
>   the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.
>
> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

In your case, the new type `char` can be either signed or unsigned depending on compiler. The value 65 can be represented by `char` regardless of signedness, so the first paragraph above applies and the value remains unchanged. For other larger values, you might have ended up with the "value cannot be represented" case instead.

This is a valid conversion between integer types, so no cast is necessary.

---

Please note that strictly speaking, the result of `sizeof(c)` etc is type `size_t` and to print that one correctly with `printf`, you must use the `%zu` specifier.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on the need for casts in the first 2 `printf` statements as `%d` expects an `int`, not a `size_t`.

Comment: @chqrlie Added a note about it.

Comment: You might extend a bit about why printing `c` does not require a cast while `"%d"` expects an `int`. The value is converted to `int` without an `int` variable involved.

Comment: @Gerhardh How to use printf isn't really relevant to the question though. There's plenty of posts regarding that elsewhere on SO.

Comment: It may be a bit unclear but for me the part "Why **when printing c**..." seems to be the main question.

Comment: I just saw that this was added afterwards and the edit was not even done by the author of the question. In that case you are right of course.

Answer (score 0):

This assignment is performed on compatible types, because char is not much more than a single byte integer, whereas int is usually 4bytes integer type (machine dependant). Still - this (implicit) conversion does not require casting, but You may loose some information in it (higher bytes would get truncated).

Comment: These are not *compatible* types as that term is defined by the C standard. The assignment is defined due to specific rules for assignments and automatic conversions, not due to compatibility of the types.

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine your program:

- `char c; int i = 65; c = i;`  There is no need for a cast in this assignment because the integer type `int` of variable `i` is implicitly converted to the integer type of the destination. The value `65` can be represented by type `char`, so this assignment is fully defined.
- `printf("%d\n", sizeof(c));` the conversion specifier `%d` expects an `int` value. `sizeof(c)` has value `1` by definition, but with type `size_t`, which may be larger than `int`. You must use a cast here: `printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(c));` or possibly use a C99 specific conversion specifier: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(c));`
- `printf("%d\n", sizeof(i));` Same remark as above. The output will be implementation defined but most current systems have 32-bit `int` and 8-bit bytes, so a size of `4`.
- `printf("%c", c);` Passing a `char` as a variable argument to `printf` first causes the `char` value to be promoted to `int` (or `unsigned int`) and passed as such. The promotion to `unsigned int` happens on extremely rare platforms where `char` is unsigned and has the same size as `int`. On other platforms, the cast is not needed as `%c` expects an `int` argument.

Note also that `main` must be defined with a return type `int`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    int i = 65;
    c = i;
    printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(c));
    printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(i));
#if CHAR_MAX == UINT_MAX
    /* cast only needed on pathological platforms */
    printf("%c\n", (int)c);
#else
    printf("%c\n", c);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```